# How does fflush work?

Tags: c, fflush

I'm not sure if I properly understand how flushing works in C. I just can't get it to work as described in multiple manuals and reference books. Here's an example with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int  x;
    char ch;

    printf("Prompt: ");
    scanf("%d", &x); /* I key in 67 and press Enter. At this very moment,
                        the input buffer should contain the ASCII codes
                        for the numbers 6 and 7 as well as the ASCII code
                        for the newline character, which is 10. The scanf
                        function is going to find the ASCII codes for 6
                        and 7, convert them to the integer 67, assign it
                        to the variable x and remove them from the
                        buffer. At this point, what still remains in the
                        buffer is the newline character. */
    fflush(stdin);   /* I want to do some more input. So, I flush the
                        buffer to remove anything that still might be
                        there, but it doesn't really look like fflush is
                        doing that. */

    printf("Prompt: "); /* I'm not going to be able to get my hands on
                           the following line of code because fflush is
                           not doing its job properly. The remaining
                           newline character is going to be read into the
                           variable ch automatically, thus not allowing
                           me to enter anything from the keyboard. */
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    printf("x: %d, ch: %d\n", x, ch);
    /*
       OUTPUT:
       Prompt: 67
       Prompt: x: 67, ch: 10
    */


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from `fflush()` not being defined on input streams as Sourav pointed out...

> I key in 67 and press Enter. At this very moment,
>                           the input buffer should contain the ASCII codes
>                           for the numbers 6 and 7 as well as the ASCII code
>                           for the newline character, which is 10. The scanf
>                           function is going to find the ASCII codes for 6
>                           and 7, convert them to the integer 67, assign it
>                           to the variable x and remove them from the
>                           buffer. At this point, what still remains in the
>                           buffer is the newline character.

And if the user did input something that is not a number, other things could have happened.

If there were non-digits *before* the first digit, **`x` will not be initialized**. You wouldn't know, because you did not check the return value 
of `scanf()`.

The user might have anticipated the next prompt (for a character), and have entered something like `67 x`, expecting the `67` to satisfy your first prompt, and the `x` your second. (And he won't be happy your program dropped part of his entry.)

Using `*scanf()` on input you cannot be **sure** is of the expected format (user input, as opposed to e.g. reading back something you yourself wrote with `*printf()`) is fragile.

So my generic advice is to **not use the `*scanf()` functions on user input, but instead use `fgets()` to read user input line-wise, and parse the input in-memory at your leisure.**

You have many much more powerful functions at your disposal that way, and you can handle error conditions more fine-grained (including the ability to give the *full* line entered in any error messages).

The below is only a rough scetch; depending on your applications, you'll want to organize this differently:

```
const size_t BUFFERSIZE = 1024;
char buffer[ BUFFERSIZE ];
long x;
char ch;
printf( "Prompt: " );
if ( fgets( buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin ) == NULL )
{
    // Error occurred, use feof() / ferror() as appropriate
}
else
{
    size_t len = strlen( buffer );
    if ( buffer[ len - 1 ] != '\n' )
    {
        // The line entered was too long for the buffer,
        // there is unread input. Handle accordingly, e.g.
        // resizing the buffer and reading the rest.
    }
    else
    {
        // You got the whole line; blot out the newline
        buffer[ len - 1 ] = '\0';

        // Assuming a decimal number first
        char * curr = buffer;
        errno = 0;
        long x = strtol( curr, &curr, 10 );
        if ( errno == ERANGE )
        {
            // Number exceeds "long" range, handle condition
        }
        else if ( curr == buffer )
        {
            // What you got was not a number, handle condition
        }

        // Keep parsing until you hit end-of-string
    }
}
```

Comment: `size_t len = strlen( buffer ); if ( buffer[ len ] != '\n' )` is always true as `buffer[ len ]` is 0.  Suggest http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359

Comment: @chux: The bane of writing such answers in the "test cases running" break at the office: No testing, think-o's ensue. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do `fflush(stdin);`, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`,

> Ifstream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

and `stdin` is not an output stream.

Comment: Hmm, then what should I use instead?

Comment: @MikhailR. many ways are there...one approach is to use `scanf("%d%*c", &x);` to discard the newline..

Comment: @SouravGhosh what if they type a space before pressing enter?

Comment: @M.M Matt sir, that is why I mentioned _too broad_ firstly, `while (getchar() != `\n`);` will also be an alternative. :)

Answer (score 2):

For completion's sake:

Some implementations do define `fflush` on input streams. Examples are [Microsoft's msvcrt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) and [GNU libc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html). Others, like the BSD libc, may additionally provide a [separate function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fpurge&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for purging the buffer.

These functions, beside being unportable, have some serious drawback: They are often used with the assumption that the buffer looks some particular way, e.g. has a single newline.

`stdin` may be connected to a file, and its buffer might contain more than just a newline. These buffered data would be skipped over, if the input stream is purged.

Further, there can be buffers outside the libc's `stdio` which aren't affected.

Therefore, you should explicitly read and discard the data you don't want.